Would like to close the bootloader on Pixel 6a
I have a Pixel 6a running Android 15 that always starts up with the message "The bootloader is unlocked and software integrity cannot be guaranteed. Any data stored on the device may be available to attackers. Do not store any sensitive data on the device. Visit this link on another device: g.co/ABH"
My guess is that I have to re-install the entire Google OS for security reasons, but when I pursue this I'm faced with a choice between Factory Image and Full OTA image.
Does the fact that the bootloader is already open have any bearing on which of these I select?
========
Full disclosure: because of my suspicious nature I've avoided getting a smart phone until now, and have finally relented after discovering GrapheneOS. However, I'm not a developer and at seventy years of age I have difficulty following technical procedures like flashing Graphene to my Pixel. This is how I ended up in this situation.

If it's any reassurance, it's expected to unlock the bootloader and see this standard warning before being able to flash a custom ROM, like GrapheneOS that is more security hardened and privacy-friendly.

Thanks Andrew. The problem here is that the Graphene web-based installer no longer sees my Pixel device, so I suspect something's gone wrong with the device drivers and I don't want to brick my device by getting overly ambitious.

Problem solved. It seems that many web browsers don't work too well with the GrapheneOS web-based installer. After having no success with Vivaldi, Brave, and Edge (all on Windows10) as a last ditch effort I tried my HP Chromebook and it went through without a hitch.
